# Style child of parent if parent of sibling contains class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a class (bold) to a parent element's (button.usa-nav-link) child (span). This parent has a sibling (ul li.active) that contains the class .active on it. If it is active, the parent's child (span) should contain class="bold".

(this) isn't picking up the parent element so I can target the child (span). I've tried :has( > .active) and a few other things with no results. Thoughts?

```js
if(jQuery("button.usa-nav-link").siblings("ul").find(".active")){
     jQuery(this).children("span").addClass("bold");
};
```

```css
.bold{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><button aria-controls="submenu-771" aria-expanded="false" class="usa-accordion-button usa-nav-link"><span>Products</span></button>
<ul aria-hidden="true" class="usa-nav-submenu" id="submenu-771">
 <li class="expanded menu-mlid-771">
  <a href="/dev/products">Products</a>
 </li>
 <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-776">
  <a href="/dev/content/imagery">Imagery</a>
 </li>
 <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-775">
  <a href="/dev/content/web-data-services">Web Data Services</a>
 </li>
</ul>
</li>
 <li><button aria-controls="submenu-773" aria-expanded="false" class="usa-accordion-button usa-nav-link"><span>Services</span></button>
<ul aria-hidden="true" class="usa-nav-submenu" id="submenu-773">
 <li class="expanded active-trail active menu-mlid-773">
  <a class="active-trail active" href="/dev/page/services">Services</a>
 </li>
 <li class="first leaf active-trail active menu-mlid-956">
  <a class="active-trail active" href="/dev/page/services#fireprogramsandtechnicalsupport">Fire Programs and Technical Support</a>
 </li>
 <li class="leaf active menu-mlid-953">
  <a class="active" href="/dev/page/services#inventoryandmonitoring">Inventory and Monitoring</a>
 </li>
 <li class="leaf active menu-mlid-777">
  <a class="active" href="/dev/page/services#mapanddatadevelopment">Map and Data Development</a>
 </li>
 <li class="last leaf active menu-mlid-955">
  <a class="active" href="/dev/page/services#scienceandtechnologyevaluation">Science and Technology Evaluation</a>
 </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: you can use `parent` or `parentsUntil`, just check out the docs!!

Comment: explain it with classes/tags instead of *elements* .. something like (When click on `button.usa-nav-link` I need to check the parent `ul` if it has `active` class or not .. if true addClass `active` to span)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef added more info.

Comment: @jasonflaherty Did you check the solution?

Comment: @Highdef, yes, that is a winner. I should have though too loop through them. Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: Also, why is this downvote? I wish that required an explanation. ...I guess this is a good answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: I think it does say for itself, as to why the loop was needed in the first place. Second, the siblings are only checking for li, the anchor could be active as well, third, closest doesn't work in the way your query demands the solution to.

Comment: @jasonflaherty And no problem :) Make sure to accept the solution if it solved your query. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this.

- You can make use of '`this`' attribute *when you loop through and **check each button*** with that **specific class**.
- When you use the 'find' function, you need to use the **length** attribute to check if it returns *0 or not* depending on the number of elements found for the value passed inside `find function`.

```js
$("button.usa-nav-link").each(function(){

if ($(this).siblings("ul").find('.active').length){
       $(this).children("span").addClass("bold");
    } 
});
```

```css
.bold{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><button aria-controls="submenu-771" aria-expanded="false" class="usa-accordion-button usa-nav-link"><span>Products</span></button>
<ul aria-hidden="true" class="usa-nav-submenu" id="submenu-771">
 <li class="expanded menu-mlid-771">
  <a href="/dev/products">Products</a>
 </li>
 <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-776">
  <a href="/dev/content/imagery">Imagery</a>
 </li>
 <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-775">
  <a href="/dev/content/web-data-services">Web Data Services</a>
 </li>
</ul>
</li>
 <li><button aria-controls="submenu-773" aria-expanded="false" class="usa-accordion-button usa-nav-link"><span>Services</span></button>
<ul aria-hidden="true" class="usa-nav-submenu" id="submenu-773">
 <li class="expanded active-trail active menu-mlid-773">
  <a class="active-trail active" href="/dev/page/services">Services</a>
 </li>
 <li class="first leaf active-trail active menu-mlid-956">
  <a class="active-trail active" href="/dev/page/services#fireprogramsandtechnicalsupport">Fire Programs and Technical Support</a>
 </li>
 <li class="leaf active menu-mlid-953">
  <a class="active" href="/dev/page/services#inventoryandmonitoring">Inventory and Monitoring</a>
 </li>
 <li class="leaf active menu-mlid-777">
  <a class="active" href="/dev/page/services#mapanddatadevelopment">Map and Data Development</a>
 </li>
 <li class="last leaf active menu-mlid-955">
  <a class="active" href="/dev/page/services#scienceandtechnologyevaluation">Science and Technology Evaluation</a>
 </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I didn't think of looping through. was focused on the parent too much.

Comment: @jasonflaherty No problem :)